# Circular button hover effect

Tags: jquery, css, button

I have found a nice effect for buttons and I would like to implement this in one of my websites. Does anyone know where I can find a (free) jquery file to implement this effect? It's the first effect you see, where the border expands in a circular shape :)

http://tympanus.net/Development/IconHoverEffects/

Comment: That's a nice animation for elements! :) But, you cannot just ask for a tool here :(

Comment: on top right there is link for tutorial http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/30/simple-icon-hover-effects/ grab from there

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan : You cannot ask SO members to provide a tool / work for you, but I keep thinking it is acceptable to asks for ideas !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example on tympanus is using CSS3 transitions instead of jquery plugins, so you are not looking in the good way to solve your problem, it would be better to check out how to animate it using CSS3 transitions directly.

EDIT : [CSS3 tutorial with w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

EDIT : [Another tutorial of CSS-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/)

```
.icon {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transition: background 0.2s, color 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.2s, color 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.2s, color 0.2s;
}

.icon:hover {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.icon:after {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: '';
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box; 
    box-sizing: content-box;
    top: -7px;
    left: -7px;
    padding: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #fff;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(.8);
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transform: scale(.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(.8);
    transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
    transform: scale(.8);
    opacity: 0;
}

.icon:hover:after {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I've added the rules used on :after pseudo-element, that display the external circle ! For information, the icon itself is using the :before pseudo-element, with an iconic font such as  [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/)

Comment: I'll have a look at it :)

Answer (score 1):

This example doesn't use jquery, it's all CSS (like most stuff on tympanus).

You will need to strip the CSS out and apply it to your own ids/classes. OR you could use their CSS file & use the same classes as they are using, but there might be stuff in it which may conflict with other styles on your site.